# Re: How to fix 'Structure Needs Cleaning' Error when the structure is on a RAID

Tags: raid

I have seen the suggestion for fixing 'Structure Needs Cleaning' on a Linux drive.  But those instructing to use fsck do not mention any special considerations for dealing with the situation when the "drive" is in fact a raid 10.  (4 x T mirrored to 8T).  Yes the raid its self had difficulties but I manages to get it "repaired" and now before I tear it all down I want to copy off the whole raid but cannot because of the structure errors.

Can I just fix it by stopping and unmount the raid, then fsck each drive followed by a restart and remount of the raid?  Don't want to burn any bridges so that I place myself even further into the wrecked zone so I am hoping for some advise.

Thank You
Nick